# No module named pyspark Error when using generic function

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am building project in pycharm IDE using pyspark.
The Spark install successfully and can be call easily from command prompt.
The Interpreter also configured correctly in project setting. I also tried with pip install pyspark.

The main.py looks like:-

```
import os
os.environ["SPARK_HOME"] = "/usr/local/spark"
from pyspark import SparkContext
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from genericFunc import genericFunction
from config import constants

spark = genericFunction.start_data_pipeline()

inputDf = genericFunction.read_json(constants.INPUT_FOLDER_PATH+"file-000.json")
inputDf1 = genericFunction.read_json(constants.INPUT_FOLDER_PATH+" file-001.json")
```

and the generic function looks like:-

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession


print('w')
def start_data_pipeline():
   #setting up spark session
   '''
      This function will set the spark session and return it to the __main__
      function.
   '''
   try:
      spark = SparkSession\
             .builder\
              .appName("Nike ETL")\
               .getOrCreate()
      return spark
   except Exception as e:
      raise

def read_json(file_name):
   #setting up spark session
   '''
      This function will set the spark session and return it to the __main__
      function.
   '''
   try:
      spark = start_data_pipeline()

      spark = spark.read \
        .option("header", "true") \
        .option("inferSchema", "true")\
        .json(file_name)
      return spark
   except Exception as e:
      raise


def load_as_csv(df,file_name):
   #setting up spark session
   '''
      This function will set the spark session and return it to the __main__
      function.
   '''
   try:

      df.repartition(1).write.format('com.databricks.spark.csv')\
                .save(file_name, header = 'true')

   except Exception as e:
      raise
```

Error:

```
Error:
Unresolved reference 'genericFunc'
"C:\Users\MY PC\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\Scripts\python.exe" C:/Capgemini/cv/tulsi/test-tulsi/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Capgemini/cv/tulsi/test-naveen/main.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pyspark import SparkContext
    ImportError: No module named pyspark

    Process finished with exit code 1
```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that PyCharm creates its own virtual environment (venv) before running a python project and that venv do not have the packages installed - in this case `pyspark`. So you need to point PyCharm to the correct python shell where the packages are available.

You should go to `File -> Settings -> Project -> Python Interpreter`

and change the Python Interpreter to correct python that has the packages. To find your python run this your python shell

```
>>> import os
>>> import sys
>>> os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
'C:\\Doc\\'
```

[image]